# Можно ли вставить HMS Iap в пакет для Google Play для российских пользователей

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing, huawei

Где-то видела, что для пользователей из России Google разрешил разработчикам добавлять сторонние sdk оплаты. Информация не проверена.
Есть ли сейчас такая возможность?
Если есть, не мог бы кто-нибудь помочь найти документ, где это сказано или опровергается?
Конкретно, хочу перейти на Huawei HMS IAP биллинг, так как я индивидуальный разработчик и более подходящей возможности покупки в приложении я не нашла.

Comment: [тык](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/11174377)

Comment: Да, спасибо, я это читала, но нигде не нашла Россию. Там отдельно написано про разные страны и, насколько я поняла, не все страны доступны для индивидуальных разработчиков. У меня, например, в консоли сейчас только поле для южной Кореи отображается. Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Вернее, Корея упоминается одна на странице сторонних апи оплаты, не уверена, что будет в случае отправки пакета.

Comment: Huawei под санкциями USA, так что это плохая идея.